# App Store Connect: New Agreement Available but no button appear

Tags: app-store-connect

I have some problems with my app store connect account. I need to update one of my existing app, but unable to do it.

The banner underneath appear, it says a new agreement is available and I need to accept it.

But the thing is, I can't see any button or link to accept the agreement. Does anyone have an idea to resolve this?

FYI: I am the account holder.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for quite a while, I found the new agreement button is available under the apple developer account page.

This is so confusing. From the app store connect page there is no link or information at all that inform us to where should I navigate, to be able to accept the new agreement.

Anyway, here it is https://developer.apple.com/account

[image]